# Is the "postgres" database always available in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a script that needs to get all the databases in a postgres cluster, and so it needs to connect to a database (it doesn't matter which) to do this.

Is it okay to assume that the "postgres" database will always be available to connect to, or if not, is there a programatic way to determine an arbitrary database in the cluster that I can connect to?

Comment: It is a reasonable assumption, IMHO. (other choices are `template0` and `template1`, but these could be removed or denied access to)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL has three "system" databases: postgres, template0, and template1. I'm pretty sure all of them can be dropped. (You might want to test this in a virtual machine.) I'm *certain* that postgres and template1 can be dropped by a privileged user. By default, template0 doesn't accept connections.

Having said that, the main purpose of "postgres" is to give you [a database to connect to](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html).

> The postgres database is also created when a database cluster is
>   initialized. This database is meant as a default database for users
>   and applications to connect to. It is simply a copy of template1 and
>   can be dropped and recreated if necessary.

So it's a reasonable assumption, but not a bullet-proof assumption. I can imagine some paranoid (careful) shops might drop "postgres" and use a different database as their internal default in case their server were compromised. That's kind of like using a non-default port for SSH.

Comment: Thank you! It's very useful to know that applications are encouraged to assume "postgres" exists

Answer (score 5):

In my personal experience, yes, it's almost guaranteed that it will exist. But, according to the PostgreSQL official documentation:

```
The database server itself does not require the postgres database to exist, 
but many external utility programs assume it exists.
```

So, you can't assume it will always be available, although in the practice, it will be available almost for sure.